# Scanning QR code crashes often - AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, avcapturesession

Am trying to scan QR code with the below code and it works fine. But sometimes it crashes with the following error.

Could not cast value of type 'AVMetadataFaceObject' (0x1b245bd28) to 'AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject' (0x1b245be68). Help much appreciated.

P.S: Am showing camera inside tabbar controller

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"
        return
    }
    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata (or barcode) then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            launchApp(decodedURL: metadataObj.stringValue!)
            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            captureSession?.stopRunning()
            captureSession = nil

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the forced downcast and use a conditional downcast (ie ? Instead of !)

Comment: let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject this one?

Comment: Which line is the crashing at?

Answer (score 4):

The use cases of a force cast are very limited, it is almost never a good idea. You should use:

```
guard let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else{
    // Display some sort of error message or handle it
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are detecting [QR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataobject/objecttype) codes and not faces:

```
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
```

Comment: this saves my day! i was getting frequent crashes.